# cannot understand error: says illegal start of expression (logical operators)

Tags: java

Here is the error that pops up:

```
Riccio_Lesson5.java:88: error: illegal start of expression
        }else if(bmi == 18.5 & <= 24.9){
                               ^
Riccio_Lesson5.java:91: error: illegal start of expression
        }else if(bmi == 25.0 & <= 29.9){
                               ^
```

Here is the code for this:

```
if(bmi < 18.5){
    System.out.print(", indicating your weight is in the\nUnderweight category for adults of your height.");
    System.out.print("\n\nTalk with your healthcare provider to determine possible causes of underweight and if you need to gain weight.");
}else if(bmi == 18.5 & <= 24.9){
    System.out.print(", indicating your weight is in the \nNormal category for adults of your height.");
}else if(bmi == 25.0 & <= 29.9){
    System.out.print(", indicating your weight is in the Overweight category for adults of your height.");
}else if(bmi >= 30.0){
    System.out.print(", indicating your weight is in the Obese category for adults of your height.");
}
```

I'm trying to say that if the bmi is equal to 18.5 or less than or equal to 24.9, your bmi will show up as normal/if your bmi is equal to 25 or less than/equal to 29.9 you are overweight.

Comment: You need two comparisons with a logical, not bitwise, and.

Comment: what `bmi == 25.0 & <= 29.9` should test? maybe you want `bmi >= 25.0 && bmi <= 29.9`

Comment: And your won't want an equals, but a greater-than equals. Although if the ranges are contiguous that won't be necessary either. A Java tutorial might be a good idea.

Comment: BTW, what if bmi is 29.95?

Comment: So if I use the && operator, would I then have to change the == to >= (greater than or equal to 18.5) so that it fulfills both conditions?

Comment: update: the error is still coming up, with the && edited in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot leave off the left side of a comparison expression in Java like we would in natural language; it always needs to be explicit.  "BMI greater than or equal to 18.5 and less than or equal to 24.9" must translate to:

```
bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9
```

Note here that I've used `>=` to catch values greater than or equal to 18.5.  I've also used `&&`, which is usually used for logical conjunctions for its short-circuiting behavior, although `&` will work just fine for logical operations.

You may also want to use `bmi < 25.0` instead of `bmi <= 24.9`, because your next `else if` condition starts with (or will start with) `bmi >= 25.0`, and you will want to catch values such as 24.95 that won't be caught with your present logic.

Similar changes are needed for the next `else if` condition.